# date_create_from_format does not give back expected result

Tags: php, date, datetime

I just tried,

```
date_create_from_format('Ym','201302')
```

And I guess because it's the 29th today, it's actually giving me back March 1st.

I was hoping to get back `2013-02-01 00:00:00`.

Is there a different function that will parse a date "correctly"? If not, I can extract it myself, not a big deal.

Comment: I'm not sure if it applies to PHP as well, but JavaScript starts counting months with 0. So March = 2. Regardless, is `March 1st` the exact result you are receiving?

Comment: @Derija93: Nope. I double checked. `201302` gives `2013-03-01 13:37:04` and `201303` gives `2013-03-29 13:37:04`

Comment: @Derija93 zero-based months are only when it returns data components as integers, not when it's parsing.

Comment: If you want a specific day of the month, you need to include it in the string, otherwise it uses today's day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If `format` does not contain the character `!` then portions of the generated time which are not specified in `format` will be set to the current system time.

> If `format` contains the character `!`, then portions of the generated time not provided in `format`, as well as values to the left-hand side of the `!`, will be set to corresponding values from the Unix epoch.

> The Unix epoch is 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.
> ([DateTime Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php))

So, adding a `!` at the beginning of your `format` string should fix your problem.

Comment: +1 this is the correct answer. Use example: `echo date_create_from_format('!Ym','201302')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`.

Answer (score 0):

[TheWolf's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19083116/65387) seems to work perfectly, but here's an alternative I started writing anyway:

```
function CompactStrToTime($str) {
    $year = strlen($str)>=4 ? substr($str,0,4) : date('Y');
    $month = strlen($str)>=6 ? substr($str,4,2) : 1;
    $day = strlen($str)>=8 ? substr($str,6,2) : 1;
    $hour = strlen($str)>=10 ? substr($str,8,2) : 0;
    $min = strlen($str)>=12 ? substr($str,10,2) : 0;
    $sec = strlen($str)>=14 ? substr($str,12,2) : 0;
    return mktime($hour,$min,$sec,$month,$day,$year);
}
```

Comment: if you are working with DateTime already, don't mix it with strtotime, mktime and similar functions. But if you still need this code somewhere, you can still shorten-it-up, like [this](https://eval.in/51536).

Comment: @Glavić: What, by adding a default? I'm not processing very many dates, and I don't much care how they get calculated :-)